# What is the code corresponding to the visual layout constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

What is the code corresponding to the visual layout constraint? I want to translate it to `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([])` format.

```
scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(scrollView)

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))

stackView = UIStackView()
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[stackView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
```

The snippet is from [Simple Scrolling UIStackView](https://gist.github.com/twostraws/a02d4cc09fc7bc16859c).

Comment: You can just directly replace view.addConstraints with NSLayoutConstraint.activate and continue to use the visualFormat if you want.

Comment: I don't want to use visual format for constraints.

Comment: OK, I can help you figure that out.  I'll have to investigate what `.alignAllCenterX` does to the resulting constraints...

Comment: Make sure you have `stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and 
`stackView.axis = .vertical`.  You probably just left those out of the question to make it more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Visual Format Language (VFL)* can create multiple constraints simultaneously, and these do.  The first three VFL's create 2 constraints each, and the last one creates one constraint.

I'd suggest using layout anchors to create the constraints.  Here is the equivalent of your code using `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` and layout anchors:

```
scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(scrollView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])

stackView = UIStackView()
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor)
])
```

---

**Notes:**

1. I investigated the effects of `.alignAllCenterX` on the resulting constraints, and that option did nothing in this case.
2. You could combine all of the constraints into a single `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` call *if* you add *both* subviews *before* creating the constraints.  I think it's clearer with two calls since each set has a single purpose.
3. `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` is smart and it adds the constraints to the appropriate views.  It is the preferred choice and has been available since iOS 8.
4. Make sure you set `stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and `stackView.axis = .vertical`. (You probably just left those out of the question to make it more concise).